# Making a 5v 12v and -12v PSU

Tags: power-supply, transformer, lighting

I'm trying to make a PSU for a Zero88 Juggler lighting desk (as ours has been misplaced and a new one is £70) and am struggling to find a transformer to be able to power it. The pin out on the back of the desk (picture attached) shows 5V 12V -12V 0V and ground. I was wondering whether anyone could help with how I would be able to craft a PSU for this?

Thanks in advance

[image: Pinout]

Comment: So, two problems: 1. *we are not a free electronics design service*, sorry. You'll need to come up with an approach of your own, at least some rough schematic of what you're going to do.

Comment: 2. a supply not only has a rated voltage, but also a maximum current, at the very least, as specification, *per output rail*. Further things of interest are often allowable ripple, noise power density limits. It's often not easy to find these requirements, so adding a bit of detail to your question on what these individual voltages are used for (own research!!) will be helpful. You know, on this whole website, you're probably the only one sitting in front of your device.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll see if I can get the current. I also know the power of the original supply is 42W. I might see if I can look at an original supply as well to help.

Comment: Hint: 780X series of DC to DC converters, you can parallel them for more current

Comment: Unless the -5 V current requirement is significant, salvage any old computer ATX power supply, bridge the PS_ON and you have all the voltages you need.

Comment: Sorry, -12 V I mean.

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual (it's on their website), pin 4 isn't connected and pin 3 (+12V) isn't used, so you just need the 5V line, which is rated at 200mA. And ground.

It'll probably work fine off any old PSU with the right rating and decent regulation. The simplest approach for a self build would be a linear design of transformer, smoothing capacitors and a 7805 regulator. However, I'm wondering if the 12V is necessary for the DMX signal or something.

Repurposing an old computer PSU might be a very cost effective solution. You'll probably have to add a load resistor or two on the 12V output(s) to ensure stable operation.

Comment: ATX supply modification would be cheap/free and simple.

Comment: 5V @ 200mA is totally doable with a cheap USB power supply

Comment: Great, thanks I think I'll be able to find an old PC one lying around and get it to work

Comment: It would be worth opening the desk up to see if that +12V line is actually connected to anything before you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I found a sata power supply lying around and also found an image of the original supply for the desk. The specifications seem fairly similar so I think I will have a go with it.

Original supply
[image: Original supply]

SATA Supply
[image: SATA Supply]

Comment: No -12 V on it. You need a DC/DC from one of the rails in order to generate it.